# PlacePicker zoom

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Is it possible to set zoom level to a `PlacePicker` `Activity`?

I set it up like this:

```
 PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
 LatLngBounds.Builder b = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

 b.include(latLng);
 builder.setLatLngBounds(b.build());

 startActivityForResult(builder.build(myActivity.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

[Official documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) mentions the default zoom...

> By default, the viewport is centered on the device's location, with
>   the zoom at city-block level.

... but how do I change it in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if there's no better answer..

I guess one could use `SphericalUtil` library and include 4 (NESW) points with a constant distance from the central point to expand the bounds, like so:

```
double offsetMeters = 200;
LatLng offsetPoint = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(latLng,offsetMeters,0);
b.include(offsetPoint);
offsetPoint = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(latLng,offsetMeters,90);
b.include(offsetPoint);
offsetPoint = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(latLng,offsetMeters,180);
b.include(offsetPoint);
offsetPoint = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(latLng,offsetMeters,270);
b.include(offsetPoint);
```

Comment: can you describe you have done to set the zoom level for place picker?

Comment: Isn't the code pretty self-explanatory? There should be a better way but I just included four equally distant points (North, East, South and West) from the central point (latLng) of the picker's view.... I don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: Post a new question with some code, maybe someone will answer :).